# UV light Skin depth for a Glass

Tags: electromagnetism, glass, amorphous-solids

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skin_effect#Formula): 
 
$\delta = \sqrt{\dfrac{\rho}{\pi \cdot f \cdot \mu_r \cdot \mu_0}}$

$\rho$ for a glass was taken as $10^{11} \text{ } \Omega \cdot m $, 
$\mu_r$ for a glass was taken as $1$ (leaving only $\mu_0$, which is $4\pi \cdot 10^{−7} \text{ H}/m$), 
 
and the $f$ for a $\text{300 nanometer}$ UV light $=\dfrac{\text{speed of light}}{\text{wavelength}} \approx \dfrac{\text{300} \cdot 10^{6}}{300 \cdot 10^{-9}} \approx 10^{15} \text{ Hz}$.


Calculating: 
 
$\delta \approx \sqrt{\dfrac{10^{11}}{\pi \cdot 10^{15} \cdot 4\pi \cdot 10^{−7}}} \approx \sqrt{\dfrac{10^{3}}{\text{39,478}}}$,


which equals $\text{5 meters}$ thick, and yet transparent glass.


The Question is, what is wrong with this calculation?
What is not taken into account? 
Since it is commonly known that UV light at this range ($300 \text{ nanometers}$ and lower) can not penetrate window glasses, that are barely a few millimeters thick.

Comment: Although I am not that confident in this area. The problem is probably the permeability. Since permeability of an object, much like permitivity/conductivity, is frequency dependant. Wikipedia formulas probably use alot of assumptions

Comment: What I said above is correct, however you're using the completely wrong formula anyway. It says above that formula, that it only works in the presence  of no dialectrics.

Comment: BTW are you using "," as the decimal point here?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft yep; at least thats what my VBScript file does.